# MongoDB Synchronizing multiple Shards

Tags: mongodb, cluster-computing, sharding

I've got the following layout [Picture Cluster](http://abload.de/img/replica_cluster0ksiw.png)

`RZ West` is my first data center A and `RZ Ost` my second data center B. As you can see one secondary database of each cluster is available in the other data center.

Is it possible to read data out of `Secondary 2 OST (B)` and add it to the master database `Primary WEST (A)` automatically?

To understand the question this solved question could be helpful [MongoDB Multiple Masters in ReplicaSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22988773/mongodb-multiple-masters-in-replicaset)

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Not a programming question. You really should direct these questions to [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) instead, which is a more suitable forum. The good people will answer that there as well.

Comment: Hi @NeilLunn unfirtunately the question isn't answered as well at [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63007/mongodb-synchronizing-multiple-shards). I don't think that it's such a horrible topic or am I wrong? :)

Comment: This isn't something supported within MongoDB. Perhaps if you give a little more details as to what you want to achieve we can help you put together a suitable work around.

Comment: @daveh For sure. We've got two productive systems in different data centers. What we want is to synchronize the data of system A (which is written to MongoDB Replica A) with the data of system B (which is written to MongoDB Replica B). 

Our goal is to have all data available in every replica set and we can read and write to that data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, I take it that you wish to write only to the local primary, but read from either replica set.

The solution would be a sharded cluster formed from your two replica sets with their current setup. You can then setup a new collection which includes [shard tagging](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/tag-aware-sharding/). You should set this up so that the data which was in DCA will stay in DCA, and the data in DCB will remain in DCB. If you setup in this manner your writes from each application will be directed only to the "local" Primary (which receives writes) for each system are located in the same DC.

When you go to read data you can use the [nearest read preference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-preference/) to read from the closest member, which given your setup will always be in the Local DC. You will need to setup a MongoS in each DC and this would be the point you connect to for your application.

Comment: I am suggesting a sharded cluster like that, yes (you need to add config servers as they are a requirement for sharding). MongoS is a router, it doesn't contain any data itself, but reads and returns data from the shards (which would be your 2 replica sets). If you specify a read preference of nearest the MongoS would direct its reads to the closest (by ping) member of the replica set that contains the relevant data for the query. This way, you could query both sets on one connection and one collection without leaving the local DC.